# Array returning only the first item in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, view, controller

I'm facing a problem that I can't solve, I have an array that only returns the first value and obviously, I need them all, the code in the controller is like this:

```
public function OnGoing(Request $request) 
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $tickets = $this->chamadosCad
        ->where('status', '=', 2)
        ->OrderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->paginate(30);

    $chamado = TiChamadosCadastro::all();

    //dd($chamado->setor);

    $SetorNome = Setores::where('id', '=', $chamado->pluck('setor'))
        ->get();

    //dd($SetorNome);

    return view('portal.TI.chamados.ematendimento', compact('user', 'tickets', 'chamado', 'SetorNome'));
}
```

If i change the line:

```
$SetorNome = Setores::where('id', '=', $chamado->pluck('setor'))
        ->get();
```

To:

```
$SetorNome = Setores::where('id', '=', $chamado->setor)
        ->get();
```

I get the error

> Property [setor] does not exist on this collection instance.

The same happens if I try to dump $chamado.

The bit of my view that regards this error is like this now:

```
<div style="display: none"> 
                @if($chamado->prioridade == 0)
                    {{$prioridade =  'Baixa', $corTabela = 'info'}}
                @elseif($chamado->prioridade == 1)
                    {{$prioridade =  'Média', $corTabela = 'warning'}}
                @elseif($chamado->prioridade == 2)
                    {{$prioridade =  'Alta', $corTabela = 'danger'}}
                @endif
            </div>
            <tr class="{{$corTabela}}">
                <td>{{$chamado->id}}</td>                                      
                <td>{{ $SetorNome->pluck('nome') }}</td>                                      
                <td>{{ $prioridade}}</td>
                <td>{{$chamado->solicitante}}</td>
                <td>{{date('d/m/Y H:m', strtotime($chamado->created_at))}}</td>
```

That's actually a lot more but is to much code, this bit is inside a `forelse`.
If i let this piece of code like it is, i get the same value on every rows and, if i change the line:

```
<td>{{ $SetorNome->pluck('nome') }}</td>
```

To:

```
<td>{{ $SetorNome->nome' }}</td>
```

I get the same error as before.
If I try to loop this same line as:

```
@foreach($SetorNome as $SetorNome)                                      
    <td>{{ $SetorNome->pluck('nome') }}</td>
@endForeach
```

I get:

> Call to a member function pluck() on bool (View:

If a take all the pluck() out, that other error returns.

I'm really don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong, I'm still learning and any help will be appreciated.

I already search in a lot of places but didn't find anything that helped me, or at least that I could understand.

If there is any question or if I couldn't explain this right feel free to ask.

Also, if there is another question about this issue please let me know.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Both `$chamado` and `$SetorNome` are collections of objects, which is why `pluck()` works, but not properties. You'll need to iterate through the collection (however, `@foreach($SetorNome as $SetorNome) ` fails because you're essentially overwriting the variable name. Use a different variable name for the right side), use `whereIn`, or take advantage of [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thanks for the tips @aynber, i'll try here...

Comment: It should be `Setores::whereIn('id', $chamado->pluck('setor'))->get()` as `pluck()` returns array and I assume you want to get array or `Setores` with corresponding `id`s.

Comment: Hi guys, i've tryied using `whereIn` and i get _Invalid argument supplied for foreach()_, with `filter` i have the array but still couldn't get the result as i was expecting in a new variable...

Comment: Is it possible for me to use a `foreach` loop inseide this controller? It will work?